# How to add a "continue shopping" button after emptying cart in Ubercart?

Tags: ubercart

This is really a weird issue. I get this on my ubercart page without any possibility for redirection:

[image]

One hint I'm eager to try is a [drupal_goto function.](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7.x)

But how do I add this to which file to which line specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you can override `uc_empty_cart()` function with `theme_uc_empty_cart()`; which returns your custom message on empty cart page.

You can get continuous shopping cart URL from Store > cart setting using `variable_get('uc_continue_shopping_url', '')`.

Example:

```
  // Default function from uc_cart.module
  function theme_uc_empty_cart() {
    return '<p>'. t('There are no products in your shopping cart.') . '</p><a href="'.variable_get('uc_continue_shopping_url', '').'" rel="continuous-shopping">continuous shopping</a>';
  }
```